# Stop item sliding multiple times in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a basic toggle list. Clicking an item title should slide down its content, and slide up the any other item content.

The following code works, but there is a problem that if I click on an item multiple times, it will slide up and down as many times it is clicked.

Is there a way to improve it so that even if you click on same item multiple times, slide it only once.

**JQuery:**

```
$(".title").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.item').removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    $('p').slideUp();
    $(this).next().slideDown();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="title">title1</div>
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="title">title2</div>
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

See the demo here, if you click on title multiple times, you will see that:

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/a7H27/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.stop()` will clear the animations which are in queue for the particular element. So that the unnecessary clicks would be ignored. Please read this to know more about [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Try this,

```
$(".title").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.item').removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    $('p').slideUp();
    $(this).next().stop().slideDown();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/a7H27/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Cancel click event if element is animated:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a7H27/4/)

```
$(".title").click(function(e){
    if($('.item, p').is(':animated')) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.item').removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    $('p').slideUp();
    $(this).next().slideDown();
});
```

Comment: I just tried out your demo, But it is not working as OP expecting.! Please make some quicker clicks on it.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use a simple if statement to test if the parent has the active class, which has the added bonus of optionally being able to collapse open panes if you need to...

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/a7H27/2/)**

```
$(".title").click(function (e) {
    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.item').removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        $('p').slideUp();
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    } else { //optionally closes open panes, remove if desired
        $('.item').removeClass("active");
        $('p').slideUp();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend using .stop(), for it stops the animations immediately, leaving an unfinished animation if clicked a second time.

I recommend checking if the `.item` has an `.active` class and if it doesn't, animate it's paragraph, like so.

JSFiddle - [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vznQj/5/)

```
$(".title").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //$('.item').removeClass("active");
    //$(this).parent().addClass("active");
    //$('p').slideUp();
    //$(this).next().slideDown();


    // Track which item we're referring to
    var item = $(this).parent('.item');
    // If item isn't active
    if(!item.hasClass('active')){
        // Remove all active classes on .item
        $('.item').removeClass('active');
        // Add class to clicked .item
        item.addClass('active');
        // Sliding all paragraphs like before might be bad in 
        // the future. Select .item paragraphs
        $('.item p').slideUp();
        // Find this item's paragraph and slide down.
        item.find('p').slideDown();
    };
});
```

Comment: Your solution is good, Though `.stop` will not work as you are thinking if we use it properly. Check out my demo.

Comment: You're right! `.stop` works well for a normal use case. For older systems running many background processes it is not a good choice. Try clicking the item rapidly (normal use case for system lag). It gets jumpy. These are things to keep in mind if speed and backwards compatibility are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$('p').stop().slideUp();
$(this).next().stop().slideDown();
```

Comment: This works, but will stop the animation if clicked to quickly, leaving an unfinished animation.